# How would I make an image fit perfectly into a div?

Tags: html, css

http://cssdesk.com/PgtbW

I want to use as much HTML and CSS as possible and the least JavaScript as possible. The image in the `spotlight` is supposed to be fitting into the square perfectly, with all pixels from left to right being shown. Basically, I want it to resize according to the screen size.

I've looked all over the web and nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Hi Jeremy!  I looked at your code, but it seems to me that there's a lot of stuff there that could be unnecessary.  Can you pare back your code example to the minimum necessary to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: Like this? http://cssdesk.com/4vQvQ

Comment: @KatieK: Oh, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `background-size:cover` to the spotlight class like in this example: http://cssdesk.com/4vQvQ

Comment: Works great, except one thing. In Chrome, it looks fine, but in Firefox and Internet Explorer, the pixels look jagged and aliased. What should I do to fix that problem?

Comment: Looks fine here in Chrome, FF, IE9, and Safari. Not sure if there is anything you can do since it's controlled by the browser.

Comment: [This](http://i.imgur.com/JWXsA.png) is what I'm talking about. The former is nice and anti-aliased while the latter is aliased.

Answer (score 0):

You can just six the size of your  according to the size of the image by JavaScript.

e.g

```
document.getElementById("Your Div Id").width="Width of the image in px";
document.getElementById("Your Div Id").Height="Height of the image in px";
```

Answer (score 0):

insert image inside div using

and apply the following css

```
div img
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Remember it wont make the image  as a background of div...